# Confidence region in copula

Tags: confidence-interval, copula

I have started to use statistical copulas in R with the package `copula`. I want to use the copula essentially as a kernel density estimator. To be precise, my plan is to simulate 1000 statistics, create a copula with these statistics, and then see if a statistic from real data fits inside the 90% confidence region of the copula.

My question is: what would be the best way of doing this with the `copula` package? The way I have worked so far is:

(1) create a copula with the simulated statistics

(2) use the `pobs` function on a matrix with both the simulated statistics and the real statistic. Then I take out the `pobs`-transformed values of the real statistic.

(3) use the `pCopula` function on the `pobs`-transformed values of the real statistic to get the distribution function value of the real statistic.

(4) If the `pCopula` value is larger than 0.05 and lower than 0.95, I say that the real statistic is within a 90% confidence region.

I am getting strange results, however. Can anyone see a flaw in my approach or do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: This sounds like a roundabout way to do something that could be accomplished directly without a copula.  Could you explain what the copula formulation might be helping you achieve?  What exactly is this "statistic" you refer to?

Comment: @whuber The copula is used because it is faster than a kernel denstiy estimator. Some examples of statistics are mean age and mean length in simulated samples from a population. The real statistics are then mean age and mean length from an actual population.

Comment: I do not understand how the copula could possibly replace the KDE unless you are using it to make a specific assumption about the joint distribution--which would seem to be contrary to the nonparametric spirit in which KDEs are employed.